# How to convert IExcelDataReader Values to string Datatype

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, exceldatareader

I am using below code to read Excel and store in Dataset.

```
     public DataSet ReadExcelDataToDataSet(Stream fileStream)
            {
                DataTable dataInExcelSheet = new DataTable();
                IExcelDataReader excelReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateReader(fileStream);
                DataSet excelDataSet = excelReader.AsDataSet(new ExcelDataSetConfiguration()
                {
                    UseColumnDataType = false
//Do we have any property here to convert all rows values to string datatype.
                });
                excelReader.Close();
                return excelDataSet;
            }
```

Is there any way to convert all values of Excel Sheet to string and store it in Dataset as String values.

**Example:**

In Excel file, for few columns I have values as 1,22.0 which are of Int32 and Double datatypes. I want to convert these values to string and then store them in Dataset as String.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @AlwaysLearning answer with a non `LINQ` version of the extension.

```
public static class DataSetExtensions
{
    public static DataSet ToAllStringFields(this DataSet ds)
    {
        // Clone function -> does not copy the data, but just the structure.
        var newDs = ds.Clone();
        foreach (DataTable table in newDs.Tables)
        {
            // if the column is not string type -> set as string.
            foreach (DataColumn col in table.Columns)
            {
                if (col.DataType != typeof(string))
                    col.DataType = typeof(string);
            }
        }

        // imports all rows.
        foreach (DataTable table in ds.Tables)
        {
            var targetTable = newDs.Tables[table.TableName];
            foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
            {
                targetTable.ImportRow(row);
            }
        }

        return newDs;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
public DataSet ReadExcelDataToDataSet(Stream fileStream)
{
    DataTable dataInExcelSheet = new DataTable();
    IExcelDataReader excelReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateReader(fileStream);
    DataSet excelDataSet = excelReader.AsDataSet(new ExcelDataSetConfiguration()
    {
        UseColumnDataType = false
    }).ToAllStringFields();
    excelReader.Close();
    return excelDataSet;
}
```

Comment: Is there a way of getting background colour with “ExcelDataReader” as per my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59410272/7586301)?

Answer (score 0):

When using `UseColumnDataType = false` ExcelDataReader returns cells as `System.Object`.

If you need to get `System.String` back you'll need to clone the `DataSet` structure, setting each `DataColumn`'s type to `System.String` as you go, and use `DataTable.ImportRow()` to do all the conversions to `System.String` for you. If you need more control of formatting (e.g.: converting Date types) you could also do the conversions explicitly.

Here's an example for you...

```cs
// NuGet reference: ExcelDataReader v3.6.0 built from https://github.com/ExcelDataReader/ExcelDataReader/ExcelDataReader
// NuGet reference: ExcelDataReader.DataSet v3.6.0 built from https://github.com/ExcelDataReader/ExcelDataReader/ExcelDataReader.DataSet
using ExcelDataReader;
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

namespace Convert_IExcelDataReader_values_to_string
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static DataSet ReadExcelDataToDataSet(Stream fileStream)
        {
            DataSet excelDataSet;
            using (IExcelDataReader reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateReader(fileStream))
            {
                var dataSetConfiguration = new ExcelDataSetConfiguration()
                {
                    UseColumnDataType = false
                };
                // This reads each Sheet into a DataTable and each column is of type System.Object
                excelDataSet = reader.AsDataSet(dataSetConfiguration);
            }

            var stringDataSet = ConvertToDataSetOfStrings(excelDataSet);
            return stringDataSet;
        }

        private static DataSet ConvertToDataSetOfStrings(DataSet sourceDataSet)
        {
            var result = new DataSet();
            result.Tables.AddRange(
                sourceDataSet.Tables.Cast<DataTable>().Select(srcDataTable =>
                {
                    var destDataTable = new DataTable(srcDataTable.TableName, srcDataTable.Namespace);
                    // Copy each source column as System.String...
                    destDataTable.Columns.AddRange(
                        srcDataTable.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
                            .Select(col => new DataColumn(col.ColumnName, typeof(String)))
                            .ToArray()
                            );
                    // Implicitly convert all source cells to System.String using DataTable.ImportRow()
                    srcDataTable.Rows.OfType<DataRow>()
                    .ToList()
                    .ForEach(row => destDataTable.ImportRow(row));
                    return destDataTable;
                })
                .ToArray()
                );
            return result;
        }

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var stream = File.Open("TestOpenXml.xlsx", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
            {
                var dataSet = ReadExcelDataToDataSet(stream);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Is there a way of getting background colour with “ExcelDataReader” as per my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59410272/7586301)?