# Get background colour with "ExcelDataReader"

Tags: c#, excel

I want to get the background colour of an Excel cell using "ExcelDataReader" library.
Can anybody give me a hint?
What I have so far is:

```
DataRowCollection sheet;
string fileName = "....";

private void OpenExcel_and_CloseExcel(string articleNumber)
{
  if (sheet != null) sheet.Clear();

  var stream = File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite); // can open already opened xls
  var reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateReader(stream); // xls, xlsx
  var result = reader.AsDataSet(); // the result of each spreadsheet is now in result.Tables[...]
  var dt = result.Tables[_tableName];
  sheet = dt.Rows;

  /* For debuging:
  string text = sheet[42][6].ToString();
  int r = dt.Rows.Count;
  int c = dt.Columns.Count;
  MessageBox.Show("text: " + text +", "+ r +", "+c); */
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Hey just curious if you found a way?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this helps but instead of "ExcelDataReader" I used Excel interop dll to make an Excel instance and set/get color in cell.

### To set color in a cell

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

Excel.Application xlApp;
Excel.WorkBook xlWB;
Excel.Worksheet xlWS;

xlApp = new Excel.Application();
xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\path\to\file.xlsx");
xlWS = xlWB.Worksheets["Sheet1"];

xlWS.Cells[1, "D"].Interior.Color = Color.GreenYellow;
```

### To get color from a cell

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

Excel.Application xlApp;
Excel.WorkBook xlWB;
Excel.Worksheet xlWS;

xlApp = new Excel.Application();
xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\path\to\file.xlsx");
xlWS = xlWB.Worksheets["Sheet1"];

int color_n = System.Convert.ToInt32((xlWS.Cells[1, "D"]).Interior.Color);
Color color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromOle(color_n);
MessageBox.Show(color.ToString()); // Outputs the color of a cell
```

Comment: Thanks; I already used this one as well before, but the problem was that dealing with large Excel files took really a long time... for an Excel sheet of 300 rows x 200 columns takes (with my format types) about 15sec, while with `ExcelDataReader` about 1-2 secs... only thing I need though is getting the background color...

Comment: @anna Please notice this [Link](https://github.com/ExcelDataReader/ExcelDataReader/issues/87) . I think the library is not meant to read cell's internal formatting